# Django Suspicious Operation

Tags: python, django, exception, heroku, amazon-s3

so I made this small app on heroku using django. 
Everything is working correctly on my computer, including this URL
 http://regina-jobz.herokuapp.com/job/search/1/1/
Unfortunately, I get a 400 error and I initially I had no means to know what went wrong.
I used the addon named "Bugsnag" to track the error and it finally showed me this :

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to 'https:/reginaemploi.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/company-logo/default-pic.jpg?Signature=P7cCZpYOlnzr7asOEjVyqHzGIgw%3D&Expires=1403269018&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAITNBWFV6BZDWPZMQ' denied.
storages/backends/s3boto.py:341 _normalize_name
storages/backends/s3boto.py:458 url
django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py:12 url
django/templatetags/static.py:106 render
django/template/defaulttags.py:196 render
django/template/debug.py:78 render_node
django/template/base.py:840 render
django/template/loader_tags.py:62 render
django/template/debug.py:78 render_node
django/template/base.py:840 render
django/template/base.py:134 _render
django/template/loader_tags.py:123 render
django/template/debug.py:78 render_node
django/template/base.py:840 render
django/template/base.py:134 _render
django/template/base.py:140 render
django/template/loader.py:169 render_to_string
django/shortcuts/__init__.py:29 render_to_response
jobSearch/views.py:177 results
django/core/handlers/base.py:114 get_response
```

Their seems to be a SuspiciousOperation Exception when accessing `https:/reginaemploi.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/company-logo/default-pic.jpg`
which is weird because the same link was working outside of Django, when I pasted it in my browser.
I read on that [link](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header-django/) that underscore ("_") might cause some problems so I eliminated all underscores from my access path. ( this is the second time I get this exception, before that I had a folder named `"company_logo"`

Can you tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it :)
The error originated from my templates where I wrote

```
 {% static object.picture.url %}
```

instead of

```
{{ object.picture.url }}
```

It was apparently using a wrong path to access my picture, which is stored on amazon s3

Thanks everyone :) I should have probably searched a little more before asking. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had the same problem. Django's `FieldFile` calls the storage class's `url()` method anyways, so it probably has something to do with that extra and unnecessary call to `static()`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the second forward slash when you include the image url. It should be

You have `https:/yourdomain/image.jpg`, it should be `https://mydomain/mypicture.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair , I checked my settings, I don't know why it appears like this. I wrote `https://` in my `settings.py`