# How to solve Django SuspiciousFileOperation during handling of static files?

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm trying to make Django web application. It worked on linux and wsl. But now I need to make Windows native development environment.

However when I try to get the static img file I get following errors.

```py
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (C:\tcgcreator\img\devirun.png) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\jidpn\tcgcreator_eternal_beta\tcgcreator\static)
```

settings.py

```py
DEBUG = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

urls.py

```
[•••]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is something I put in the img tag

```
<img class="img_card" src="/static//tcgcreator/img/devirun.png">
```

My django version is 4.2.3 and python version is 3.11.4

I looked at [Django Suspicious Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334404/django-suspicious-operation) and tried the same thing. But it didn't work for me.

Comment: I came across this again while surfing through SO and I thought I should leave a comment. Doing this: `<img class="img_card" src="/static/tcgcreator/img/devirun.png">` is not a good idea. [See reasons why you should use the static tag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#how-to-deploy-static-files)

Answer (score 1):

The path to the static image file you are providing in your template `img src` here is not correct.

```html
<img class="img_card" src="/static//tcgcreator/img/devirun.png">
```

Django immediately recognizes this as a [SuspiciousFileOperation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/exceptions/#suspiciousoperation)
To rightly specify the static file Django serves for you, see [How to manage static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS.)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#how-to-manage-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)
One more thing, consider deleting your `__pycache__` folder since you are moving from WSL back to full Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted all pycache files but I still get the same error. I'm sorry that I didn't mentioned but I used the following code to determine the static url  'var static_url = "{% get_static_prefix %}/tcgcreator";'  and src="+static_url+/img/"+img_url+". Also when I use url like   background-image:url({% static '/tcgcreator/img/background'%}/{{Background}}); but it gets 404 error

Comment: Ohh actually the last one was just a suggestion. The second paragraph should help you. See [How to manage static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS.)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#how-to-manage-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)

Comment: it seems like i put extra slash to url. after i got rid of it it worked!thank you for help

Comment: Did you also get rid of the `//` after `static` in the url making it just `/`? If the answer helped, consider accepting it.